# Wso2: Configuring rsync for Deployment Synchronization

Tags: linux, shell, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I've set up a clustered deployment for 2 mi nodes and I'm trying to enable rsync(remote synchronization) using the following documentation: [Rsync for wso2](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/deployment/deployment_synchronization/#using-network-file-share-nfs)

I've set everything up, but when I try to run the final cron expression (`*** sh  *  *   *   *     /home/ubuntu/setup/rsync-for-depsync/rsync-for-ei-depsync.sh=**`), I get the following error:

```
nodes-list.txt: 1: root@<my_server_ip1>:~/home/ubuntu/mi/wso2mi_server1-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server: not found
nodes-list.txt: 2: root@<my_server_ip2>:~/home/ubuntu/mi/wso2mi_server2-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server: not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a cron job, you need to add it to the special file known as a `crontab`. Just running the command in the CLI won't work.

Step 1: Edit your crontab with the following command. This will prompt to choose a editor to open the file.

```
$ crontab -e
```

Step 2: Add the cron expression and the command. In our case, we need to execute the `rsync-for-ei-depsync.sh` script every minute. To do that add the following line to the end of the crontab file you opened in the step 1.

```
*   *  *   *   *  sh /home/ubuntu/setup/rsync-for-depsync/rsync-for-ei-depsync.sh
```

For more information on Cron Jobs refer https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-ubuntu-1804

Comment: By 'Add the script' do you mean as in the script that's already present in the rsync-for-ei-depsync.sh file?

Comment: Once you have opened the crontab file, you need to add the cron expression and the command. In our case the command is `sh /home/ubuntu/setup/rsync-for-depsync/rsync-for-ei-depsync.sh`. This will execute the rsync-for-ei-depsync script every minute.

Comment: I actually did do this, and then I even restarted my cron service, but there is no change. My carbonapp from the original node is not getting copied to the other server node.

Comment: Do you still get the error? If you manually run the script, does the files get synced?

Comment: If I manually run 'sh /home/ubuntu/setup/rsync-for-depsync/rsync-for-ei-depsync.sh', after entering the passwords of the both the servers I get an error as follows:
rsync: [Receiver] mkdir "/home/ubuntu/home/ubuntu/mi/wso2mi_server1-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(787) [Receiver=3.2.3]

I have no idea why it's appending an extra 'home/ubuntu/', because the path i've mentioned in the script as the mi_server_dir is /mi/wso2mi_server1-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server

Comment: Can you share the rsync-for-ei-depsync.sh file as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252752/discussion-between-ahinsa-and-sanoj).

Comment: After removing the ~ from the nodes-list.txt like you suggested it turns out it was a path issue all along. Thanks @sanoJ !!!